# Unable to do Cassandra TDE

Tags: jakarta-ee, cassandra

I am trying to encrypt the data at table level in Cassandra DSE 3.2.4

Following example was tried:

```
create TABLE test2 (empname text primary key)
  WITH compression =
  { 'sstable_compression’: 'Encryptor', 
 'cipher_algorithm' : 'AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding',  
'secret_key_strength' : 128,
  'chunk_length_kb' : 1 };
```

Response: I am always getting the error "Bad Request: Could not create Compression for type 
org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.Encryptor"

Please help if you have faced any such issues.

I Referred the following link: http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/3.2/datastax_enterprise/sec/secTDEtblcrypt.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.

We had a chat with Cassandra expert, they recommended that
DSE 3.2.4 has been end of service life since November 2015. It would be wise to upgrade from this version to a supported version of DSE.

We will upgrade to the new version and then try.

Answer (score 1):

You need JCE installed to use "'secret_key_strength' : 128"
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Also DSE is currently at version 4.8 for the latest major release, you should start there.